# Browser keeps "connecting" after jQuery Ajax request times out

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a list of IP addresses to a couple of servers that need to be pinged to see if they are running. Their IP addresses are stored in the `data-ip-address` attributes of a list of `span` elements, the Javascript function reads them in order, pings each of them, and displays the result. A more simplified version of the full function is this:

```
function pingServers() {
  if($('span[data-ping-this]').length > 0) {
    element = $('span[data-ping-this]:first');
    $(element).removeAttr('data-ping-this');
    var url = $(element).attr('data-ip-address');

    $.ajax({
      url: url, 
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      timeout: 4000,
      success: function(response) {
          displaySuccess();
      },
      error: function(something){
          displayWarning();
      }
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
      pingServers();
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

The main thing is that there is a timeout defined, and that timeout definitely is working, because after 4 seconds of no response, I do get my warning displayed. But my browsers, both Firefox and Chrome, are still showing a status message that they are connecting (in the bottom-left corner). Firefox shows the `Connecting to <ip address>` message, while Chrome only shows `Connecting...`, and the favicon in the tab keeps being the animated loading icon.

If I keep the tab open, this goes on forever. If I change the tabs enough times, the status message (and the loading icon) eventually goes away (never without changing tabs). Another interesting thing is that, after it goes away, if I initiate this function again via Javascript (not by reloading the page), then the `Connecting` message doesn't show up at all anymore. Even though it should in this case. How I do this, is by simply returning the `data-ping-this` attribute to one of the `span` elements, and then run the function again.

```
$('span:first').attr('data-ping-this', 'true');
pingServers();
```

So, is this something that can be fixed on a jQuery side, and if so, how? Or is it a bug in the browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly: This is the bug of JSONP.

Explanation: The JSONP is not a real XmlHttpRequest, so **it is not an Ajax call**. JSONP is a hacky attempt to perform cross-domain requests by requesting some remote script from a different domain, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to learn more.

What jQuery does inside, it performs this JavaScript call by adding

```
<script src='your_pinging_address'></script>
```

This is the only way to make a JSONP request. Then it comes to timeout, which they do most likely with `setTimeout`, so they found out on jQuery side that timeout is reached and they call your `callback` function; meanwhile the browser has no idea about this timeout because it is artificial, so it goes on waiting for a remote script.

In other words: every Ajax request but JSONP has a timeout on the browser side. The JSONP timeout is a piece of jQuery art.

I cannot point you to a line of the code where they serve the timeout in the current jQuery. I had a similar problem couple of years ago with some old jQuery version, but logically everything should stay as it was.

Comment: Ok I see, it makes perfect sense. I suppose it would solve the problem if, instead of JSONP'ing the external server, I would JSON my own URL, where a server-side request to the external server would be made.

Comment: This could solve that, right. What you could also do to make the solution more clean is make a thin proxy server which will transparently call your ping targets and add to their response `CORS` headers (you'll need them because the proxy is on another domain). I like this way more because it stays away from your main app.